# Connecting a Web Form to a Dynamic Data List

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, dynamic-data-list

I just started using Liferay but have encountered a problem. I've set up a page to use as a Blog Entry point. I added the Blog Entry to the page but when I go to click "Add Blog Entry" it doesn't do anything.

Is this a bug with Liferay 6.1? I checked the permissions and I have permissions to add to this (naturally, because I am the admin), so if I can't do it then an average user won't be able to either.

What gives?

Comment: you could add some sourcecode, that way people can get into your problem a bit more specifically...

Comment: i.e. view the source code by right clicking on the page?

Comment: the code you used to add the button?
so no, Java code